# Partial View is not rendering td elements inside foreach razor tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using a List of Products as a Model for my Partial view. In the partial view I am using a foreach loop to get the values of Product class and trying to render it to users. In the partial view I've written this code:

```
@model Project.ViewModel.ListofProductsVM
@using Project.Models
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Cost
    </th>
</tr>
@{
    foreach (Products prod in Model.products)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@prod.Name.ToString()</td>
            <td>@prod.Cost.ToString()</td>
        </tr>

    }
}
</table>
```

I can see the headers **"Name"** and **"Cost"** in the page but Product Name and its Cost is not rendering. When I am checking the source code in HTML it is showing me this HTML only:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Cost
    </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

While debugging I can see the values are correctly getting passed to Partial Views. Even the **"@prod.Name"** and **"@prod.Cost"** is showing me the correct value. But it is not rendering it to HTML. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@{ }` means that this is c# code block, you can fix the problem by writing your foreach loop code this way:

```
@foreach (Products prod in Model.products)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@prod.Name.ToString()</td>
        <td>@prod.Cost.ToString()</td>
    </tr>

}
```

and if you want to stick with your way then you have to specify to render that as html like:

```
@{
   foreach (Products prod in Model.products)
   {
     @:<tr>
         @:<td>@prod.Name.ToString()</td>
         @:<td>@prod.Cost.ToString()</td>
     @:</tr>

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment but it's still not working. Does it possible that my jQuery file is interfering with this? I am actually posting the data via $.post method to the Action method and returning a cshtml view from that method. On $.post method of jQuery I am putting null as Function Success.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem. In my case, all I needed was to add "@" before the foreach nested in an if statement. This is a pared down snippet of my working code

```
C# Model class:

public class MyModel
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}

CSHTML file: 

@model List<MyProject.Models.MyModel>

@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="row" >
        <table>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>@item.FirstName @item.LastName</tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

But it's the same answer that another user gave you.